# React: is there a better pattern for higher-order component rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

Here's a practical example.

```
import React from 'react';
require('./Headings.css');

let HeadingMixin = HeadingComponent => class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return <HeadingComponent {...this.props} />
  }
}

function Heading(props){
  return (<h1 className={`${props.type}Heading`}>{props.text}</h1>)
}

Heading.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
      React.PropTypes.string,
      React.PropTypes.element,
  ]),
  type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['page', 'modal', 'sub', 'section']).isRequired,
}

export default Heading;
```

Now, the actual HTML rendered by each component varies by element and `className`.

```
<h1 className="pageHeading">{props.text}</h1>
<h2 className="modalHeading">{props.text}</h2>
```

etc. with `sub` and `section`.

Now, between `propTypes`, elements, and `classNames`, is there a better way of choosing what to render and keeping them all in sync without using a switch statement?

As an alternative, but similar example, here's how I have done this with an Icon class.

```
import React from 'react';
require('./Icon.css');

const editGlyph = <path d="M5 14l-3-3 8-8 3 3zM11 2l2-2 3 3-2 2zM0 16l3-1-2-2" />;
const backGlyph = <path d="M2 7.994L8.137 16h4.312L6.31 7.994 12.45 0H8.136" />;
const addGlyph = <path d="M9.008 7.132V1H7.104v6.132H1v1.904h6.104v6.132h1.904V9.036h6.104V7.132" />;
const requiredGlyph = <path d="M4.79 3.42V1H3.655v2.42l-2.27-.857L1 3.59l2.27.815-1.392 1.95.964.662 1.392-2.055L5.71 7.017l.88-.663-1.414-1.95 2.334-.813-.428-1.027" />
const informationGlyph = <g transform="translate(0 .61)"><path d="M6.857 5.143h-2.57V6h.856v2.57h-.857v.86h3.428v-.86h-.857" /><ellipse cx="6" cy="3.429" rx=".857" ry=".857" /><path d="M6 0C2.687 0 0 2.687 0 6s2.687 6 6 6 6-2.687 6-6-2.687-6-6-6zm0 11.143C3.164 11.143.857 8.836.857 6S3.164.857 6 .857 11.143 3.164 11.143 6 8.836 11.143 6 11.143z" /></g>;

let iconGlyph;

export default function Icon(props) {

  switch (props.glyph) {
    case 'add':
      iconGlyph = addGlyph;
      break;
    case 'back':
      iconGlyph = backGlyph;
      break;
    case 'edit':
      iconGlyph = editGlyph;
      break;
    case 'required':
      iconGlyph = requiredGlyph;
      break;
    case 'i':
      iconGlyph = informationGlyph;
      break;
    default:
      iconGlyph = null;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <svg
      id="icon"
      className={[`icon ${props.className}`]}
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      aria-labelledby="title"
    >
      <title id={props.title}>{props.title}</title>
      {iconGlyph}
    </svg>
  )
}

Icon.propTypes = {
  glyph: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['add', 'back', 'edit', 'i', 'required']).isRequired,
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  title: React.PropTypes.string,
}
```

I don't know what it is, but I can't shake the feeling that there is a more elegant way to handle this. Perhaps a Decorator with some params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following. [Demo](https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/XKpWKr).

```
const { oneOf, string } = PropTypes

// save all your options in hash
const icons = {
  edit: <path d="M5 14l-3-3 8-8 3 3zM11 2l2-2 3 3-2 2zM0 16l3-1-2-2" />,
  back: <path d="M2 7.994L8.137 16h4.312L6.31 7.994 12.45 0H8.136" />,
  add: <path d="M9.008 7.132V1H7.104v6.132H1v1.904h6.104v6.132h1.904V9.036h6.104V7.132" />,
  required: <path d="M4.79 3.42V1H3.655v2.42l-2.27-.857L1 3.59l2.27.815-1.392 1.95.964.662 1.392-2.055L5.71 7.017l.88-.663-1.414-1.95 2.334-.813-.428-1.027" />,
  i: <g transform="translate(0 .61)"><path d="M6.857 5.143h-2.57V6h.856v2.57h-.857v.86h3.428v-.86h-.857" /><ellipse cx="6" cy="3.429" rx=".857" ry=".857" /><path d="M6 0C2.687 0 0 2.687 0 6s2.687 6 6 6 6-2.687 6-6-2.687-6-6-6zm0 11.143C3.164 11.143.857 8.836.857 6S3.164.857 6 .857 11.143 3.164 11.143 6 8.836 11.143 6 11.143z" /></g>
}

// Icon is stateless
const Icon = ({ type, className, title }) => (
    <svg
      id="icon"
      className={[`icon ${className}`]}
      viewBox="0 0 16 16"
      aria-labelledby="title"
    >
      <title id={title}>{title}</title>
      {/* Assuming type is the same as key in icons */}
      {icons[type] || null}
    </svg>
)

Icon.propTypes = {
  // make this constain "dynamic"
  glyph: oneOf(Object.keys(icons)).isRequired,
  className: string,
  title: string,
}
```

Comment: So, how about the Heading example? That one is trickier because you don't know which HTML element to render ahead of time.

Comment: Not really. https://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/NrdWjO?editors=0010 You can either use `cloneElement` or a function that takes children and returns a header.

Comment: I mean, I guess it's the same premise as the `<path>` elements I used for the SVG/Icon examples.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Thanks! Any further comments in regards to decorators?

Comment: I haven't played much with decorators actually. Kinda don't like yet another syntax (`@BlahBlah()`). But a function that takes params and returns a function that takes component and returns another component sounds ok :)